# Laravel 5.6 y Vue Valores por defecto

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Laravel 5.6 y Vue.js 2 que me está costando más de lo que pensaba.

He leído varios artículos y preguntas en esta comunidad y en todos lados he entendido que lo normal es utilizar componentes de Vue.js para pasar valores por defecto.

Al utilizar el motor de plantillas Blade para cargar un formulario por ejemplo tenemos el siguiente formulario:

```
<form method="{{ action('Controlador@metodo', $modelo) }}">
    <input 
        type="text" 
        name="propiedad1"
        @if(old('propiedad1'))
        value="{{ old('propiedad1') }}"
        @elseif(isset($modelo) && $modelo->propiedad1)
        value="{{ $modelo->propiedad1 }}"
        @endif
        v-model="propiedad1"
        @focusout="miFuncion">
    <input 
        type="text" 
        name="propiedad2"
        @if(old('propiedad2'))
        value="{{ old('propiedad2') }}"
        @elseif(isset($modelo) && $modelo->propiedad2)
        value="{{ $modelo->propiedad2 }}"
        @endif
        v-model="propiedad2">
</form>
```

Bueno, por razones lógicas (creo) lo anterior no funciona porque estamos mezclando valores que son puestos en el campo antes que el DOM se cree con campos que se crean después.

La solución "sencilla" es crear un componente, registrarlo y adaptarlo... Pero, ¿no hay una solución más fácil?

Comment: cual es tu codigo javascript

Comment: ¿importa? el cambio necesario es en éste formulario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es relativo decir que es más fácil o no, pues eso depende ya de cada persona.

Para resolver el problema tienes varias opciones, de las cuales voy a nombrar un par típicas, esperando que alguna de estas te parezca "más fácil":

1. a. Utilizar templates inline

   https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Inline-Templates

   Si bien no tendrás la potencia de la reutilización del componente con este método, puedes hacer el proceso completo en tu archivo de blade:

   ```
    <my-component inline-template>
      <div>
        <p>These are compiled as the component's own template.</p>
        <p>Not parent's transclusion content.</p>
      </div>
    </my-component>
   ```

   b. X-templates

   Similar al anterior, el template se define en un tag `<script>`con `type="text/x-template"`

   ```
    <script type="text/x-template" id="hello-world-template">
      <p>Hello hello hello</p>
    </script>

    Vue.component('hello-world', {
      template: '#hello-world-template'
    })
   ```
2. Mantener el componente en un archivo externo y pasar los valores que llegan de Laravel como "props" desde Blade:

   Componente Vue

   ```
    Vue.component('child', {
      props: ['message'],
      template: '<span>{{ message }}</span>'
    })
   ```

   Blade

   ```
    <child message="{{ $myVar }}"></child>
   ```

   Controlador Laravel (o lo que sea que llame la vista)

   ```
    $myVar = 'Hola';

    return view('message', compact('myVar'));
   ```

Comment: Ahora mismo estoy utilizando componentes Single-File, es que me parece tedioso crear un componente sea el que sea cada vez que Laravel interactúa con Vue.js. Se agradece igual, pensé que había una solución más "rápida" (fácil está mal usado).